# Delphi: Wrong unit added unit to uses clause of source file when component is placed on a form

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I have a weird situation with a component of mine: **I cannot get the Delphi IDE to add the correct units in the source code when the component is placed on a form**. Not only are the wrong units included but the right ones (which I attempted to add using a `TSelectionEditor` descendant) not included in some cases.

The components are supposed to be a replacement for the standard TOpenDialog/TSaveDialog component. They are actually proxy component that will instantiate the correct type (either the base dialog or a custom made one) based on some global configuration.

I have written several units implementing all the necessary classes and components, some of them should included everywhere the component is used:

- `git.dialogs.pas` is where the `TComponent` descendant registered are implemented (as well as all utility and public functions and classes)
- `git.dialogs.interfaces.pas` contains all the interfaces used to interact with the components and should be included in order to access implementation-dependent properties and methods

The registration of the components is placed in a unit called 'git.dialogs.registration.pas'. It contains a `TSelectionEditor` descendant that overrides the `RequiresUnits` method as follow:

```
uses System.Classes, GIT.Dialogs, DesignEditors, DesignIntf;

type
  TGITDialogSelectionEditor = class(TSelectionEditor)
  public
    procedure RequiresUnits(Proc: TGetStrProc); override;
  end;

procedure register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('GIT Dialogs', [GIT.Dialogs.TGITFileOpenDialogCpn, GIT.Dialogs.TGITFileSaveDialogCpn]);
  RegisterSelectionEditor(GIT.Dialogs.TGITFileOpenDialogCpn, TGITDialogSelectionEditor);
  RegisterSelectionEditor(GIT.Dialogs.TGITFileSaveDialogCpn, TGITDialogSelectionEditor);
end;

{ TGITDialogSelectionEditor }

procedure TGITDialogSelectionEditor.RequiresUnits(Proc: TGetStrProc);
begin
  inherited;
  Proc('GIT.Dialogs');
  Proc('GIT.Dialogs.Interfaces');
end;
```

That class is then registered in the usual `register` procedure using `RegisterSelectionEditor`.

In theory, when I drop one of these components on a form, the IDE shoudl automatically add the `GIT.Dialogs` and `GIT.Dialogs.Interfaces` units to the interface uses clause of the source file. Yet, it does not:

- It adds the `GIT.Dialogs.Interfaces` correctly.
- It adds an unlisted unit `GIT.Dialogs.FileDialog.Base` which contains a couple of other `TComponent` descendant used internally but not registered anywhere.
- If the source file already contains the `Dialogs` unit (from the VCL), then the `GIT.Dialogs` unit is not added.

**How can I fix this situation?** The adding of the `GIT.Dialogs.FileDialog.Base` unit isn't much of a problem since it's going to be linked anyway anytime the component is used but the fact that the `GIT.Dialogs` file isn't added require a manual fix of every form where the component is dropped or used.

Comment: Have you tried to specify the `Dialogs` unit as `Vcl.Dialogs` instead?

Comment: it will indeed fix the problem but I still need to manually adjust all existing forms.

Comment: Are you using unit scope names in your project that are in conflict with the units required?

Comment: @PaulMichael Nope. Most of our projects (there are actually about 130 different projects in our app) have been initially ported from Delphi 6 so there are a LOT of implied namespaces but none are conflicting.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the default VCL units fully, i.e. `Dialogs` should be specified as `Vcl.Dialogs`. Not only will this resolve this specific issue when dropping such a component on a form, but it will help eliminate [other problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16639555/757830) as well. Get accustomed to use fully qualified unit names.

For existing forms, there is no other way then to rewrite their unit clauses. A multi document search and replace tool could be handy then.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it is only a partial answer: it gives one hint at what could be done to avoid one of the issue I describe but not really how to fix it and doesn't explain why the problem is happening or why the wrong unit is included.